# Fail to import Mapbox Direction API

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

Correct me if i'm wrong.
I'm using mapbox api especially for navigation, now i'm confused and stopped because I can't import the API. I have followed documents from Mapbox itself but I still can't. Sorry for my bad english, i still learn :)

This my build.gradle(app)

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.kks.treking"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

//Google Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'

//Mapbox
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0'
implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.1.0') {
    exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
}
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:5.1.0'
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:ui:1.1.0"

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03'
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"}
```

And i got this error :
Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/navigation/ui/1.1.0/ui-1.1.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Mapbox Navigation SDK version > 1.0 ( you are implementing `com.mapbox.navigation:ui:1.1.0` ), the way to access the Maven repository to download the SDK libraries has changed.

You now need to create a secret access token and use it to access the maven repo, where the libraries are located.

Please also see the official documentation:

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/#configure-credentials

Your module level build.gradle should contain this:

```js
allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
      authentication {
          basic(BasicAuthentication)
      }
      credentials {
        // Do not change the username below.
        // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username). 
          username = 'mapbox'
          // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
          password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```